# AdobeSign REST API and ETag

Tags: php, digital-signature, etag, echosign

I'm trying to get my ETag code but I don't find it.

The header response I get contains no Etag:

```
Metadata x-request-id : 3969d42d-e4fe-457c-b9c6-90c003ce9072 
content-type : application/json 
status : 200
```

I use this url : https://api.eu1.echosign.com/api/rest/v6/agreements/XXXXXXXXXX

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I could not see any reason to not receive eTag in the response headers of GET /agreements/{agreementId} endpoint, eTag support has been added in Sign from V6 version onwards as per which all the GET based endpoints(except the listing ones like GET /agreements) returns eTag header in the response.

Are you sure the endpoint you invoked was GET /{agreementId} and not GET /agreements? The reason I am asking is because listing endpoints like GET /agreements do not return eTag which is exactly what you are seeing.